# Python xml2csv xmlutils program need

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have a set of code on a recently installed machine I need to activate. Basically it is a script that convert xml style .dat file into a .csv file by creating a temporary file as an intermediary and converting the text using a convert() function. This appears to use the source code from the pypi.org site.

```
from xmlutils.xml2csv import xml2csv
import sys

xml_source = sys.argv[1]
obj_name = sys.argv[2]
filename_temp = xml_source + '.temp'
filename_csv = xml_source.replace('.dat','') + '.csv'

fin = open(xml_source)
fout = open(filename_temp, "wt")
fout.write("<root>")
for line in fin:
    fout.write( line.replace("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>", '') )
fout.write("</root>")
fin.close()
fout.close()

converter = xml2csv(filename_temp, filename_csv)
converter.convert(tag=obj_name)
```

Below is a sample of the input in the xml format that gets translated line by line grouped into one record in the .csv file by the  tag. The output will be one line of a .csv file.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Account>
  <Name>Alta Paints &amp; Coatings  Inc</Name>
  <Type>Non Customer</Type>
  <RecordTypeId>012E0000000PR3uIAG</RecordTypeId>
  <ShippingStreet>136 W 3300 S</ShippingStreet>
  <ShippingCity>Salt Lake City</ShippingCity>
  <ShippingState>UT</ShippingState>
  <ShippingPostalCode>84115-3704</ShippingPostalCode>
  <Phone>801-466-9625</Phone>
  <Sic>5198</Sic>
  <NumberOfEmployees>16</NumberOfEmployees>
  <Description>PAINTS, VARNISHES, AND SUPPLIES</Description>
  <Sales_Channel__c>NAAO</Sales_Channel__c>
  <Xerox_Address_1__c>136 W 3300 S</Xerox_Address_1__c>
  <Xerox_City__c>Salt Lake City</Xerox_City__c>
  <Duns__c>197857873</Duns__c>
  <Legal_Name__c>ALTA PAINTS &amp; COATINGS, INC.</Legal_Name__c>
  <Secondary_Name__c />
  <Latitude__c>40.699928</Latitude__c>
  <Longitude__c>-111.895096</Longitude__c>
  <Map_Status__c>G_GEO_SUCCESS</Map_Status__c>
  <Xerox_County__c>SALT LAKE</Xerox_County__c>
  <Xerox_State__c>UT</Xerox_State__c>
  <Xerox_Zip_4__c>3704</Xerox_Zip_4__c>
  <County__c>SALT LAKE</County__c>
  <Department__c>1</Department__c>
  <Franchise__c />
  <County_Code__c>035</County_Code__c>
  <Domestic_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c>197857873</Domestic_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c>
  <Global_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c>197857873</Global_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c>
  <Headquarters_DUNS_Number__c>197857873</Headquarters_DUNS_Number__c>
  <Location_Employee_Qty__c>16</Location_Employee_Qty__c>
  <Xerox_Zip_Code__c>84115-3704</Xerox_Zip_Code__c>
  <Org_Group_Code__c>1</Org_Group_Code__c>
  <Parent_DUNS__c />
  <Potential_Copy_Dupl_Qty__c>4974.4</Potential_Copy_Dupl_Qty__c>
  <Potential_Printing_Sys_Qty__c>10152.0</Potential_Printing_Sys_Qty__c>
  <Telephone_Last_4__c />
  <Subsidiary_Indicator__c>0</Subsidiary_Indicator__c>
  <Trade_Name__c />
  <XNAC_Code__c />
  <XNAC_Division__c />
  <Zip_4__c>3704</Zip_4__c>
  <Customer_Indicator__c>0.0</Customer_Indicator__c>
  <Franchise_Parent__c />
  <Telephone_Area_Code__c>801</Telephone_Area_Code__c>
  <Telephone_Exchange__c>466</Telephone_Exchange__c>
  <Total_Lsr_Prtg_Vol__c>0.0</Total_Lsr_Prtg_Vol__c>
  <Open_Sales_Channel__c>USCO</Open_Sales_Channel__c>
  <Estab_Copy_Volume__c>0.0</Estab_Copy_Volume__c>
</Account><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Account>
  <Name>Alta Paints &amp; Coatings  Inc</Name>
  <Type>Non Customer</Type>
  <RecordTypeId>012E0000000PR3uIAG</RecordTypeId>
  <ShippingStreet>136 W 3300 S</ShippingStreet>
  <ShippingCity>Salt Lake City</ShippingCity>
  <ShippingState>UT</ShippingState>
  <ShippingPostalCode>84115-3704</ShippingPostalCode>
  <Phone>801-466-9625</Phone>
  <Sic>5198</Sic>
  <NumberOfEmployees>16</NumberOfEmployees>
  <Description>PAINTS, VARNISHES, AND SUPPLIES</Description>
  <Sales_Channel__c>NAAO</Sales_Channel__c>
  <Xerox_Address_1__c>136 W 3300 S</Xerox_Address_1__c>
  <Xerox_City__c>Salt Lake City</Xerox_City__c>
  <Duns__c>197857873</Duns__c>
  <Legal_Name__c>ALTA PAINTS &amp; COATINGS, INC.</Legal_Name__c>
  <Secondary_Name__c />
  <Latitude__c>40.699928</Latitude__c>
  <Longitude__c>-111.895096</Longitude__c>
  <Map_Status__c>G_GEO_SUCCESS</Map_Status__c>
  <Xerox_County__c>SALT LAKE</Xerox_County__c>
  <Xerox_State__c>UT</Xerox_State__c>
  <Xerox_Zip_4__c>3704</Xerox_Zip_4__c>
  <County__c>SALT LAKE</County__c>
  <Department__c>1</Department__c>
  <Franchise__c />
  <County_Code__c>035</County_Code__c>
  <Domestic_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c>197857873</Domestic_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c>
  <Global_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c>197857873</Global_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c>
  <Headquarters_DUNS_Number__c>197857873</Headquarters_DUNS_Number__c>
  <Location_Employee_Qty__c>16</Location_Employee_Qty__c>
  <Xerox_Zip_Code__c>84115-3704</Xerox_Zip_Code__c>
  <Org_Group_Code__c>1</Org_Group_Code__c>
  <Parent_DUNS__c />
  <Potential_Copy_Dupl_Qty__c>4974.4</Potential_Copy_Dupl_Qty__c>
  <Potential_Printing_Sys_Qty__c>10152.0</Potential_Printing_Sys_Qty__c>
  <Telephone_Last_4__c />
  <Subsidiary_Indicator__c>0</Subsidiary_Indicator__c>
  <Trade_Name__c />
  <XNAC_Code__c />
  <XNAC_Division__c />
  <Zip_4__c>3704</Zip_4__c>
  <Customer_Indicator__c>0.0</Customer_Indicator__c>
  <Franchise_Parent__c />
  <Telephone_Area_Code__c>801</Telephone_Area_Code__c>
  <Telephone_Exchange__c>466</Telephone_Exchange__c>
  <Total_Lsr_Prtg_Vol__c>0.0</Total_Lsr_Prtg_Vol__c>
  <Open_Sales_Channel__c>GIS</Open_Sales_Channel__c>
  <Estab_Copy_Volume__c>0.0</Estab_Copy_Volume__c>
</Account><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Account>
  <Name>Sun &amp; Moon Cafe</Name>
  <Type>Non Customer</Type>
  <RecordTypeId>012E0000000PR3uIAG</RecordTypeId>
  <ShippingStreet>22929 Highway 99</ShippingStreet>
  <ShippingCity>Edmonds</ShippingCity>
  <ShippingState>WA</ShippingState>
  <ShippingPostalCode>98026-8468</ShippingPostalCode>
  <Phone>425-977-2929</Phone>
  <Sic>5812</Sic>
  <NumberOfEmployees>9</NumberOfEmployees>
  <Description>EATING PLACES</Description>
  <Sales_Channel__c>NAAO</Sales_Channel__c>
  <Xerox_Address_1__c>22929 Highway 99</Xerox_Address_1__c>
  <Xerox_City__c>Edmonds</Xerox_City__c>
  <Duns__c>031593575</Duns__c>
  <Legal_Name__c>SUN &amp; MOON CAFE</Legal_Name__c>
  <Secondary_Name__c />
  <Latitude__c>47.791194</Latitude__c>
  <Longitude__c>-122.337749</Longitude__c>
  <Map_Status__c>G_GEO_SUCCESS</Map_Status__c>
  <Xerox_County__c>SNOHOMISH</Xerox_County__c>
  <Xerox_State__c>WA</Xerox_State__c>
  <Xerox_Zip_4__c>8468</Xerox_Zip_4__c>
  <County__c>SNOHOMISH</County__c>
  <Department__c />
  <Franchise__c />
  <County_Code__c>061</County_Code__c>
  <Domestic_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c />
  <Global_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c />
  <Headquarters_DUNS_Number__c />
  <Location_Employee_Qty__c>9</Location_Employee_Qty__c>
  <Xerox_Zip_Code__c>98026-8468</Xerox_Zip_Code__c>
  <Org_Group_Code__c>0</Org_Group_Code__c>
  <Parent_DUNS__c />
  <Potential_Copy_Dupl_Qty__c>994.5</Potential_Copy_Dupl_Qty__c>
  <Potential_Printing_Sys_Qty__c>1976.67</Potential_Printing_Sys_Qty__c>
  <Telephone_Last_4__c />
  <Subsidiary_Indicator__c>0</Subsidiary_Indicator__c>
  <Trade_Name__c />
  <XNAC_Code__c />
  <XNAC_Division__c />
  <Zip_4__c>8468</Zip_4__c>
  <Customer_Indicator__c>0.0</Customer_Indicator__c>
  <Franchise_Parent__c />
  <Telephone_Area_Code__c>425</Telephone_Area_Code__c>
  <Telephone_Exchange__c>977</Telephone_Exchange__c>
  <Total_Lsr_Prtg_Vol__c>0.0</Total_Lsr_Prtg_Vol__c>
  <Open_Sales_Channel__c>USCO</Open_Sales_Channel__c>
  <Estab_Copy_Volume__c>0.0</Estab_Copy_Volume__c>
</Account><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

On my previous machine, I was able to enter the path of the python conversion script name, the xml style .dat file name, the Account handle and process accordingly.

Example:

```
C:\data\convert_xml_to_csv.py C:\data\csv\2020-02-13-estab-insert.dat Account
```

At first, I got an error message that the program wasn't available, so I eventually found the page to download the latest version of Python (v 3.8.1). I selected the executable x86-64 version of the download. After that, the command just goes to the next line without any action or anything processed. I'm not sure if I have to download anything else off the xmlutils source code page or what action to take next. I may need to be walked through the rest of the process to activate this script on a new machine. It was transferred once before but the creator is no longer with the company. Is anyone able to help me?

Joao,

So I downloaded the latest version of Python (version 3.8.1), identified the path of the .exe install file and added it to the Path in environmental variables. The paths are in screenshots 2 and 3 below:

I then tried to run my script from the Powershell, however, it simply skipped to the next line without creating an output file. So then I tried to run the same script on the Command Prompt and it yielded that the xmlutils module was not found.

So it looks like I may have to download the xmlutils package from the PyPl site. But it doesn't look like there's a clear way for me to do that at this point with running a .tar.gz file.

Update: 2/18/20

I believe I have successfully installed the latest version of the xmlutils python package via the pip command. Once I did that, I tried to convert a file again where it doesn't recognize part of the code. My only guess with this error at this point is that it's an error related to an updated version of these program. Is anyone able to make the necessary tweaks from here based on this information?

Update: 3/5/2020

So after installing the xmlutils and the setuptools package where both are located in the path for Environment Variables, running the script now does in fact create the cloned temporary file this script customary has done. However, it leaves the destination file of the finished output blank for the .csv file. Anyone have any other suggestions in regards to correcting this?

[xml2csv python script result - Mar 5th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nhOb.png)

[Conversion error with xmlutils installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yTKr.png)

[Command Prompt Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ih1D.png)

[Python Environment check result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OElDH.png)

[Python Path image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmIgs.png)

[Environmental variable path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TornO.png)

Comment: Your "environment" is an image?

Comment: It's a screenshot of what happens when I ran the suggested command. It just went to the next line and did not return anything as the screenshot indicated.

Answer (score 0):

When invoking python scripts from the terminal, you should pass the scripts as arguments to the python call.

First of all, when you installed Python, did you add it to the PATH environment variable?
Run the following command, and report the output:

```
python -V
```

If the command runs fine, and prints your Python version in the command prompt, you can now invoke your script by running:

```
python C:\data\convert_xml_to_csv.py C:\data\csv\2020-02-13-estab-insert.dat Account
```

Let me know if you still have issues

**Edit**
In response to your Powershell `Get-command` output, you either do not have Python (in which case go through step 1), or you just do not have it in the PATH environment variable (skip step 1 and go directly to step 2).

**Step 1: Install Python**

- Go to [Python's website](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and download a Python version of your
  choice (for that script, I think you're good with any version of
  Python 3). For Python 3.7, for example, download [this file](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.6/python-3.7.6-amd64.exe);
- Open the executable you just downloaded, and choose "Install Now", or "Customize Installation" if you'd prefer choosing the Install location, but write down that location, if you go with the latter option;
- *You can select here to add Python to the PATH environment variable, but I purposefully ignored it to cover the other scenario*.

**Step 2: Adding Python to your PATH environment variable**

- Before you start this step, you'll need the path to your Python executable. If you followed step 1 and chose the default install location, it will be something along the lines of `C:\Users\<your user here>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\`
- Navigate to the environment variables windows (System properties->Advanced Tab->Environment Variables, or just press the windows key and search for environment variables);
- In the System variables box, search for the Path entry, select it and choose to edit the variable;
- Now's a good time to double check that there're no Python related directories there (there probably aren't, given the screenshot you've showed). Select New, and a new line will show up, insert the path you've taken notice of;
- Accept the changes;
- Now open a new powershell and try out the command once again;

Comment: João, when I typed in the <python -V> command, there was nothing returned. It just went to the next line. I'm adding a screenshot that illustrates this. I'm not sure if a reboot is warranted or need further instruction to add Python to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Since you're using powershell, can you tell me what's the output of `(Get-Command python).Path`?

Comment: I included the path in the edit of the post for the screenshot. FYI, there does not appear to be any file size (0 KB) and I'm not able to move it.

Comment: @JMMurty39, you're editing my answer. I'd rather you edited your own question with the information, because I'm going to edit my answer as you provide me with more information. Now, it seems you either don't have Python installed, or Python is not on the PATH. I'm going to edit my answer in a way that allows you to cope with either scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Per python.org:

> If the first line of a script file starts with #!, it is known as a “shebang” line. Linux and other Unix like operating systems have native support for such lines and they are commonly used on such systems to indicate how a script should be executed. This launcher allows the same facilities to be used with Python scripts on Windows and the examples above demonstrate their use.

Source: [Python.org:Shebang lines](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines)

My suggestion is to add shebang lines (yes, even in Windows) to the beginning of your Python script.  It should run without prefacing the script name with 'python'.

Hope this helps.